# Incomplete installation with unsupported locale

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I was installing postgresql on Ubuntu 12.04 (Digital Ocean droplet). The locale variables in my environment gets transported to the DO box.

When postgres is installed via `apt-get install postgresql`, it appears to succeed. However no default cluster is created, and postgresql is not added as a service. This happens silently. I realised what was going on when attempting to run `pg_createcluster` manually failed.

Some questions arising from this:

- how can I be alerted that the install hooks aren't being run?
- after fixing the locale, I removed (and purged) the `postgresql` package; however the default cluster *still* wasn't created. What was preventing this? How can I ensure that install hooks are being run?

Comment: Perhaps this person run into the same problem as you? [They found and documented a solution](http://solutions4linux.blogspot.com.au/2014/09/solving-no-postgresql-clusters-exist.html).

Comment: Hi Ziggy, thanks for the link --- that's the same workaround I arrived at, but doesn't address the two questions I raise (regarding getting the install hooks to run, so I don't have to manually create the cluster).

Comment: Maybe some error messages would help?

Answer (score 0):

Install the package locales-all and your postgresql will start up.